# How to check if column value has "value"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I want to check if value of "Acceptance" is "Accepted" and if it has that value- .Sum else i want to get 0, but have some problms with finding correct syntax. I cant get "Acceptance" value

My method

```
public decimal Prices2(string term)
{
   var kl= db.Order.Where(x => x.Client == term && x.Acceptance == "Accepted");
    if (term != null && kl.Acceptance == "Accepted" )
    {                       ^^//Element does not contain definition"Acceptance"
        return kl.Sum(x => x.Price);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

how I get "term"

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetClient(string term)
{
    return db.Order.Where(x => (term != null && x.Client.Contains(term)) || (term == null)).OrderBy(c => c.Client).Take(10).Select(a => a.Client).Distinct();
}
```

When i try this:

```
return db.Order.Where(x => x.Client == term && x.Acceptance == "Accepted").sum(x=>x.Price)
```

I get error when there is no "Accepted" order for client

> System.InvalidOperationException: „The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.”

How can i check first if there is Accepted order for client and return 0 if there istn?

Comment: This is because the variable `kl` is an `IEnumerable<Order>` where the `Client` property is equal to variable `term` given as a parameter and where `Acceptance` is set to "Accepted"

Comment: ok, i understand that `Acceptance` isnt a method so i cant use it like that, but how can i check value of that column to make calculations or get 0?

Comment: Do you want to get the sum of all accepted order's prices for a given client?

Comment: return db.Order.Where(x => x.Client == term && x.Acceptance == "Accepted").sum(x=>x.Price);

Comment: @Ammar yes i want to sum all accepted orders but i get error when there is no accepted order for client because its null

Comment: So, a client can have multiple orders. order `Acceptance` value can be `"Accepted"` or `null` or some other value. what you want to get is the sum of all prices of orders that its `Acceptance` value is `"Accepted"`? what if it's `null`? what do you want to do? sum it or leave it?

Comment: if value is accepted i want to sum all accepted orders, but if is something else i want to get 0

Comment: In your latest edit, you mentioned that you got an error when running @uk2k05 code , what is that error? are you sure that `Price` is not nullable? can you provide the structure of `Order` model?

Comment: `System.InvalidOperationException: „The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.” ` i get this if there is no Accepted orders for Client, so i try to check first if there is Accepted order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Assign the query to one variable,

```
var orders = db.Order.Where(x => x.Client == term && x.Acceptance == "Accepted");
var result= orders.Count() > 0 ? orders.Sum(x=>x.Price) : 0.0M;
return result;
```

You're return type of method should be **decimal**

.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code will not work because variable `kl` is of type `IEnumerable<Order>` which doesn't have a property `Acceptance`.

The code mentioned by @uk2k05 in the comments section will solve your problem:

```
return db.Order
    .Where(x => x.Client == term && x.Acceptance == "Accepted")
    .Sum(x => x.Price);
```

But another problem will occur, that's because `Sum` method returns `Nullable<Decimal>`, while your method `Prices2` returns `decimal`. [Click to see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.8)

To solve this problem you can use the following code instead:

```
return db.Order
    .Where(x => x.Client == term && x.Acceptance == "Accepted")
    .Sum(x => x.Price) ?? 0;
```

That will return the value returned by `Sum` or 0 if the returned value is `null`.

Comment: problem is that you cant use `??` for "decimal" or "int", so i get another error

Comment: Why not? see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) `int? a = null; int b = a ?? -1; Console.WriteLine(b);  // output: -1`. `Sum` method returns `Nullable<Int32>` which is equal to `int?`, have you tried the code? have you got any errors by using it? Also, please provide the type of `Price` in your `Order` model.

Comment: `Price` type is decimal, i try this code and i get error that i cant apply operator "??" to arguments type "decimal" or "int"